# What is the effective way to get multi timeframe data in Pinescript the optimized way?

Tags: pine-script

I am using the following method to get ohlc data. But in this code there are un necessary repetitions which could make the code slow if we use many requests like this or calling the function inside another functions etc.

Code:

```
tf_1 = 'D'
tf_2 = 'W'
tf_3 = 'M'

get_ohlcv(timeframe, data, index) => 
  request.security(symbol=syminfo.tickerid, timeframe=timeframe, expression=data[index], gaps=barmerge.gaps_off, lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)

prev_close_1 = get_ohlcv(tf_1, close, 1)
prev_close_2 = get_ohlcv(tf_2, close, 1)
prev_close_3 = get_ohlcv(tf_3, close, 1)

prev_volume_1 = get_ohlcv(tf_1, volume, 1)
prev_volume_2 = get_ohlcv(tf_2, volume, 1)
prev_volume_3 = get_ohlcv(tf_3, volume, 1)
```

Is there any fastest way to get these data for multiple timeframes. Will arrays and for loops can make it better? How to make it short and clean with minimum codes?

Answer (score 1):

Shortening the code does not mean better performance. You should know how pinescript works and which functions/methods are expensive.

Using loops is generally not a good idea as your script will be executing on each bar, you will get a performance penalty.

Coming to your specific question, you can pass tuples to `security()` and it will return a tuple. This way you would reduce the number of `security()` calls. Of course, you can only do that if the tickerid and timeframes are the same.

```
get_ohlcv(timeframe, data, vol, index) => 
  request.security(symbol=syminfo.tickerid, timeframe=timeframe, expression=[data[index], vol[index]], gaps=barmerge.gaps_off, lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)

[prev_close_1, prev_volume_1] = get_ohlcv(tf_1, close, volume, 1)
[prev_close_2, prev_volume_2] = get_ohlcv(tf_2, close, volume, 1)
[prev_close_3, prev_volume_3] = get_ohlcv(tf_3, close, volume, 1)
```